# unable to view table design in microsoft sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have microsoft sql server management studio installed for existing databases and I can connect and write queries without a problem.  However I experience problems when right clicking on the table to open  the design view.  I get the following error, has anyone seen this before?

If I click okay on this error message the right click context menu displays, i.e. displaying options for new table, design  view, select top 1000 rows, edit  top 20 rows etc.. and then I get the following error message (see image 3).

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Error message**

[image]

**Version of SQL**

[image]

**If I click design view in the right click context menu**

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It means your Management Studio's version is not >= the version of SQL Server. 
If you, for example, use Management Studio 2008 R2 to connect to SQL Server 2014, you'll get this message.

You'll need to install the latest version of SSMS.

If both versions show 2008, it's still possible you have a different version, because there is SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.